# How to call a paper or book holding charms/incantation/magic formula?

Tags: fiction, fantasy, historical-fiction

Hope the title is clear enough. I'm  also looking for any vocabulary related to the act of writing magic ( 'runes' as a magical writing system for example).

Comment: Welcome to Writing.SE! I think questions like this are better suited to [English.SE](https://english.stackexchange.com/); their [topic guidelines](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) suggest that questions along the lines of "what's the word for XYZ" are on-topic there.

Comment: You ask two questions.  Please ask them one at a time so that each can be answered and voted upon separately.

Comment: @kkoscr  Your queston is non grammatical.  It should be "What to call a paper or book..."

Answer (score 2):

To answer your main question.  A book containing spells and rituals is a [Grimoire](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=grimoire).  The term is widely used in modern Wicca and other areas.

Answer (score 0):

"Runes" such as the Elder Futhark are alphabets which we tend to think of as used for magic, although that wasn't their only purpose. "Rune" has been used more generically of late. But that is an alphabet or set of symbols - but it sounds like you are looking for a term for the act of writing? Like "inscribing"? I second @chenmunka that the term is "grimoire" for a book of spells and rituals.

Answer (score 0):

**Fantasy Junkie:**

Okay, this isn't a writing answer as much as a fantasy/D&D geek answer. This is only a sampling, and looking up synonyms should get you more. Fantasy literature is rich with this stuff, as are games like D&D. just start digging and there's no end to the material.  A lot of religious terminology can be applied to magical writing, so this is also a good place to look.

Any *old* words can give things a magical feel.  Magic is old, so **scrolls** are often described. They aren't printed, so "**inscribed**" would be how they are written. For example, the Egyptians would inscribe magic spells onto silver scrolls that they wore as amulets. Use **ink** or **pigments**, and apply them with a **quill** or **stylus**.
"Runes" are good as magical symbols, as are **glyphs**, **sigils**, **seals** or even **hieroglyph**s. I agree that a "grimoire" is a good magic book, as is a **spell book** or **tome** and could also be referred to as a **codex**, **libram**, **manual** or **folio**. Specific spell books may have special names, like the Necronomicon (anything "-nomicon" sounds magical). Many magical things have magical writing on them, like **amulets**, **charms**, **periapts**, **phylacteries**, **talismans** or **fetishes**.

Answer (score 0):

If this is just a single paper holding your incantation, I would call it a scroll. A collection of scrolls could be then joined into a *spell book* or, if written as a single work, a Grimoire as noted by Chenmunka.